# Is there ever any reason to discretise continuous ground truth if doing classification?

Tags: regression, classification, continuous-data, discrete-data, multi-class

Is there a case where discretising continuous response improves classification performance?

For example:

A response variable is in the range 0 to 99.
There are 10 classes defined by the following set of ranges $Sr = \{0-9,10-19...89-99\}$

Does it always make more sense to use regression models for this task, or can discretising and multi-class classification be beneficial?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is purely based on what you really want to predict. Let's say that I have a restaurant and have the characteristics of my customers and want to predict how many time they do spend on it. Is the time important? Whether they spent 59min or 60min inside it? This is a perfect case where you could make the time spent inside the restaurant discrete (e.g. being for 30min is bad, 30-60 average, etc). Do you have real case to discuss? Any other thought?